# Grep newsletter bounce mails for emails

Tags: email, grep, newsletter, email-bounces

I've sent out a newsletter and am watching now the inbox of the bounced mails. I'd love to grep all mails in the mail user directory on the mail server for the email addresses. What I fail to find out is how I can grep for anything between "<" and ">" as most of the bounce mails have a line like this:

```
<some_user@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27]
```

Any help on learning grep by this example greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: While that doesn't help you in the current instance, many people now encode the recipient's email address in the sender address, so bounces can be mapped easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be of help:

```
grep '<[^>]*@[^>]*>' input
```